# Access HiveConf from SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark 1.6.2, it was possible to access the HiveConf object via the below method.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html#hiveconf()

Can anyone let me know how do the same in Spark 2.0.2, from the SparkSession object?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the Hive configuration by getting the Spark conf via `spark.conf.getAll` and then accessing individual properties. To get databases, tables, functions, etc. you can access these via `spark.catalog`.

```
val spark = SparkSession().builder()
    .appName("MyApp")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()

// Get all configuration properties
val config = spark.conf.getAll

// Get the Hive metastore dir
val hiveDir = config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir")

// List databases
val dbs = spark.catalog.listDatabases
dbs.show

// List tables
val tables = spark.catalog.listTables
tables.show
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call method `SparkSession.enableHiveSupport()`  and then work with SparkSession Instance itself.

Refer this example from spark documentation.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

HiveContext has been deprecated. See here.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html